# Angular interpolation not working. Data is written to console but interpolation does not work

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Data is written to console but interpolation does not work.
There was no problem in my other project. I compared the codes, no difference

**pers-detail.component.ts**
There was no problem in my other project. I compared the codes, no difference

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Dep } from 'src/app/models/dep';
import { Pers } from 'src/app/models/pers';
import { DepService } from 'src/app/service/dep.service';
import { PersService } from 'src/app/service/pers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pers-detail',
  templateUrl: './pers-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pers-detail.component.css'],
  providers:[PersService,DepService]
})
export class PersDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private persService:PersService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private depDervice:DepService) { }
 
  per1!:Pers1;
  
  deps:Dep[]|undefined;


  
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
      this.getById(params["id"]) 
    });

    this.depDervice.getDep().subscribe(data1=>{
      this.deps=data1;
      console.log(this.per1)
    });
  }
  getById(id:any){
    this.persService.getPersById(id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.per1=data
    });
  }
}
```

Service is working correctly

**pers-detail.component.ts**

```
<form  >
<div class="form-group">
  <div s class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="validationCustom01">{{per1?.adsoyad}}</label>
    
    <input  readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01"  value="{{per1?.adsoyad}}" required>
 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="validationCustom01">Ad Soyad</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01"  value="{{per1?.adsoyad}}" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="validationCustomUsername">Telefon</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01"  value="{{per1?.telefon}}" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="validationCustom03">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" value="{{per1?.email}}" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" >
    <option *ngFor="let dep of deps" [value]="dep.id">{{ dep.ad }} </option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button routerLink="/pers-component"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

</form>
```

**console**

Data is written to the console as an array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Ktc.png)

Comment: NOTE: If you want to make "two binging" use [`[(ngModel)]="..."`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control) **not** `value={{...}}`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which interpolation is not  working?

Answer (score 0):

From the code and image, it seems you `console.log(this.per1)` is actually an array of one object, not an object itself. correct code to `this.per1= this.data[0]`

```
 getById(id:any){
    this.persService.getPersById(id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.per1=data[0] // data is an array so extract the object from it.
    });
  }
```

Also you are binding the HTML incorrectly, if you only bind it with value like this `value={{ per1?.adsoyad }}` you are just setting the initial value.
if you want the respective proeperty value inside the object to be updated when you update the input, use `ngModel`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01"  *[(ngModel)]="per1?.adsoyad" required>
```

Comment: Does not work this code

Comment: what is not working? are you saying that value are not being set or not being updated